# How to replace Spacy English model with spacy.load("en_core_web_lg") model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

For changing definition of IS_CURRENCY in the language model, used the below code.

```
from spacy.lang.nl import EnglishDefaults, English

def is_currency(text):
    """
    Custom function used for detecting currency symbols.
    
    :param text: The text that is to be checked.
    :return: A boolean.
    """
    # Stripping punctuation
    table = str.maketrans({key: None for key in string.punctuation if key != "$"})
    text = text.translate(table)
    
    all_currencies = ("฿", "US$", "C$", "A$", "₺", "₹", "৳", "₩", "Mex$", "₣", "E£")
    if text in all_currencies:
        return True
    return False
    
    
class CustomEnglishDefaults(EnglishDefaults):
    lex_attr_getters = {**EnglishDefaults.lex_attr_getters,  IS_CURRENCY: is_currency}


class CustomEnglish(English):
    Defaults = CustomEnglishDefaults

nlp = CustomEnglish()
doc = nlp(text)
```

How to replace EnglishDefaults, English with `spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")` in the above code? After the change it should still use the custom `is_currency()`.

This is because of need to keep using `spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")` for consistency in the project to get same tokens, POS, lemma etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but it's kind of a pain because of details related to registering and handling a custom language. (You would create a new empty pipeline with the custom language and then manually copy all the relevant parts of `en_core_web_lg` including tokenizer settings, strings, vectors, and all pipeline components. Your final pipeline would require the custom code that registers the custom language under a new name.)

What would be easier is to register a custom token extension that does the same thing, with something like:

```
Token.set_extension("is_currency", getter=is_currency) # getter arg is a Token
doc[0]._.is_currency
```

The main reason to add it using a custom language would be if you want to use `IS_CURRENCY` as a `tok2vec` feature for a new trained pipeline component or if you need the attribute to be really fast for a `Matcher` pattern. (You can still use custom extensions in `Matcher` patterns, it's just a bit slower.)

`en_core_web_lg` does not use `IS_CURRENCY` as a feature for any components, so the model predictions will not be affected by whether you use a custom language or a custom extension.